# Im trying to make a grid using TRIANGLE_STRIP, but the vertex is not getting connected

Tags: javascript, p5.js

So im trying to create a grid using p5.js, webgl application. I tried the following code, the problem is that the grid is getting generated but it is not connecting the rows.

```
let cols , rows;
let scl = 20;
let pi = Math.PI;
let w = window.innerWidth;
let h = window.innerHeight;
function setup()
{
    createCanvas(w,h,WEBGL);

    cols = w / scl;
    rows = h / scl;
}

function draw()
{
    background(0);
    translate(0,h/4,0);
    translate(-w/2,-h/2,0);
    rotateX(pi/3);

    stroke(255);
    noFill();
    for(let y =0; y < rows ; y++ )
    {
        beginShape(TRIANGLE_STRIP);
        for(let x = 0; x < cols; x++)
        {
            vertex(x*scl,y*scl);
            vertex(x*scl,(y+1)*scl);


        }
        endShape(CLOSE);
    }
}
```

This is what i got

[image]

This is what i want to get

[image]

The expected output is a grid using triangle strip.
The output im getting is a grid without the row lines connected.

Comment: Tried with endShape(CLOSE), it does not make a perfect grid

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue, can you please post the full code, including the perspective projection and transformations?

Comment: @Rabbid76 Sure. I have edited the full code. its using javascript and p5.js

Comment: https://editor.p5js.org/Benjamin-Davies/sketches/varUiUYiK

Comment: @BenjaminDavies Yea i have tried this, the problem is with the diagonal lines.. after some area it does not connect to the edge

Comment: @BenjaminDavies yeah i removed the  CLOSE from endShape(CLOSE)  it seems to be working. Thank you!